# Python - Multiprocessing pool.map(): Processes don't do anything

Tags: python, dictionary, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pool

I am trying to use the python multiprocessing library in order to parallize a task I am working on:

```
import multiprocessing as MP

def myFunction((x,y,z)):
    ...create a sqlite3 database specific to x,y,z
    ...write to the database (one DB per process)

y = 'somestring'
z = <large read-only global dictionary to be shared>

jobs = []
for x in X:
    jobs.append((x,y,z,))

pool = MP.Pool(processes=16)
pool.map(myFunction,jobs)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Sixteen processes are started as seen in `htop`, however no errors are returned, no files written, no CPU is used.

Could it happen that there is an error in myFunction that is not reported to STDOUT and blocks execution?

Perhaps it is relevant that the python script is called from a bash script running in background.

Comment: did you place the extra "," in "jobs.append((x,y,z,))" in purpose?

Comment: In the function definition: `def myFunction((x,y,z)):` are the extra parenthesis on purpose?

Comment: well I thought to make it a tuple...

Comment: The "extra" comma is fine. It's not the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `import multiprocessing.dummy as MP` instead of `import multiprocessing as MP`? `dummy` uses threads instead of actual processes which helps with debugging a.

Comment: Regardless of why your program isn't working, this is a bad idea. You will have 16 processes each competing to write data to the hard disk which will slow things down significantly.

Comment: It's writing in bulks and was not really I/O bound when I tried a bash-based approach before

Comment: It does not seem to report errors because I just found one and it was not printed

Answer (score 1):

The lesson learned here was to follow the strategy suggested in one of the comments and use `multiprocessing.dummy` until everything works.

At least in my case, errors were not visible otherwise and the processes were still running as if nothing had happened.

Comment: Now I have the case that for two datasets, it totally works. For another (very large one), it works with threads but with processes same problem as described above occurs. Are there some kind of size limitations? Memory was not overflowing...